# How to create a record in a model while creating a record in another model in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

In my custom application i want to create automatically a record in my custom model while i create a sale order.

```
    class custom_sale_order(models.Model):
        _inherit='sale.order'

        time1 = fields.Date('TIme1')
        time2 = fields.Date('TIme2')

    class demo(models.Model):   
        name = 'demo'

        time3 = fields.Date('TIme1')
        time4 = fields.Date('TIme2')
```

while a sale order is creating i want to create a record in demo model and also should fetch the time field from sale.order and save in demo model. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `create` method of the `sale.order` class and inside this method you can create a record in the demo model and access to `values` of the current model.

For example:

```
class custom_sale_order(models.Model):
    _inherit='sale.order'

    time1 = fields.Date('TIme1')
    time2 = fields.Date('TIme2')

    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        # here we call to the parent create method
        res = super(custom_sale_order, self).create(values)

        # here we create a record in the demo model
        # and we can access to the values of the current model
        self.env['demo'].create({
            'time3': values['time1'],
            'time4': values['time2']
        })

        return res
```